# Error: Cannot send value to non-payable function GETH

Tags: ethereum, solidity, geth

Code contract:

```
pragma solidity <0.7.0;

contract contr{

  function money()public payable{
     msg.sender.transfer(5 ether);
  }
}
```

ABI contract: `[{"inputs":[],"name":"money","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}]`

I call the function from the geth console this way: **contr.money.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], value: 50000000000000000000})**

also called like this: **contr.money.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: contr.address, value: 50000000000000000000})** The error does not chang

в

Comment: Check out https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18585/splitter-contact-is-payable-modifier-missing

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20760#issue-580263987

You have to add `"payable": "true"` to the ABI.